# Not able to write to console using syscall in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu, att

I am trying to write manually using syscall in at&t syntax. I use the command `gcc -nostdlib file.s` to compile the code.

This is my code:

```
.section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "abc\n"

.text
exit:
    movq $0, %rdi
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall

.globl _start
_start:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    mov $44, %rax
    pushq %rax

    movq $1, %rax
    movq .LC0(%rip), %rsi
    movq $4, %rdx
    syscall

    call exit
```

I used this table http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/ to find syscall info. I have been scratching my head for two hours.

When i run the program it doesnt print anything.

Comment: Use `strace` and `gdb` to debug your program.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems

- You don't set %edi (the fd to write to) prior to calling sys_write, so it will write to whatever happens to be in %edi.  Now since this is the first thing to run in a newly started process, that will be 0, so it will write to stdin.  Since stdin is generally the same terminal as stdout, this is ok
- You load your string into %esi, rather than the address of the string. The instruction

  `movq .LC0(%rip), %rsi`

will load 8 bytes from memory at .LC0 into rsi.  Try

```
lea .LC0(%rip), %rsi
```

instead